# Vertical spacing in tabular, hyperref package

Tags: tables, spacing, hyperref

I am compiling this code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcounter{MS} %\renewcommand*{\theMS}{MS\arabic{MS}} % milestones

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{p{2cm}|l}
No. & Title \\
\refstepcounter{MS} \theMS \label{MS1} & this line takes too much vertical space  
\\
-- & this one is OK  
\\
\refstepcounter{MS} \theMS \label{MS2} & this line takes too much vertical space
\\
\end{tabular}

Reference to the first row: \ref{MS1}.
I need package hyperref for \url{url.com} 
\end{document}
```

I get a table that uses too much vertical space in those rows in which I have the stepcounter:

[image]

Can anyone advise how to get rid of this? If I remove the package `hyperref` it is working OK, but I need that package for other purposes in my document.

Comment: It's in the column definition: `p{2cm}`. Change `2cm` to anything lower than that. You can use other unit length as well, such as `mm`, `pt`, etc. You may want to get more familiar with [tables](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables)

Comment: No, that is not the cause. I am not talking about the width of the columns, I am talking about the height of the rows containing `\refstepcounter{MS} \theMS \label{MS1}`.

Comment: I see. My mistake. I am not sure what causes it. Try to wrap the counter `\theMS` around `\smash{...}` that is `\smash{\theMS}`.

Comment: use `\leavevmode\refstepcounter{MS}`

Comment: Thanks, @UlrikeFischer, this works!